# Import Error: module object has no attribute 'check_specifier' error

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, tornado, setuptools

On my Buildbot virtual environments, I have been facing a weird error with installing tornado which is a dependency of `sphinx-autobuild==0.6.0`.

```
>>> pip install --upgrade sphinx-autobuild==0.6.0

Collecting tornado>=3.2 (from sphinx-autobuild==0.6.0->-r towerportal/requirements.txt (line 76))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/d1/3be271ae5eba9fb59df63c9891fdc7d8044b999e8ac145994cdbfd2ae66a/tornado-5.0.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-Bpw6k7/tornado/setup.py", line 192, in <module>
    **kwargs
  File "/spare/local/buildslave/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/spare/local/buildslave/slaveA/demoA/build/virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
  File "/spare/local/buildslave/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/spare/local/buildslave/slaveA/demoA/build/virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 325, in finalize_options
    ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
  File "/spare/local/buildslave/slaveA/demoA/build/virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2310, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/spare/local/buildslave/slaveA/demoA/build/virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2320, in resolve
    raise ImportError(str(exc))
ImportError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_specifier'
```

My setuptools version is 39.0.1. Fortunately reinstalling setuptools using `pip install -I setuptools` tends to fix the problem. But my real question is what does reinstalling the same package with same version name really changes such that it resolves the problem? Has `setuptools` been erroneously released with different codebase for same version?